# How to install two graphic card drivers: HD4000-3000 and GeGorce 710M?

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

I have a notebook with 2 graphic cards.

How can I install the HD4000-3000 drivers and GeForce 710M without GT-GTX?

(Yes I know the system settings > proprietary drivers but this option is OUTDATED!)

And when I'm launching csgo with this easy install I'm getting an OpenGL driver error telling to update drivers etc.

Comment: If you could kindly update you question with the exact output of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install recent drivers type the following in a terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
```

> I'm launching csgo with this easy install I'm get the (OpenGL driver error) update drivers

That's probably because you're using nouveau driver, which doesn't support all OpenGL versions.

For the future: Try to be more detailed when you post question on the site. It really helps community to have a descriptive title and more info in the question about your system.

Comment: How to delete this nouveau drv?

Comment: If you installed Nvidia's driver, it would replace it.

Comment: Thanks I'm now burning in to USB a Ubuntu 14.04.2 now I'm on windows 10